# How can I group by a navigation property member in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have three tables holding `Users` `Groups` and their association, `UserGroups` as laid out in [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2e9d8/2/0) fiddle:

I am trying to obtain the maximum level among the users' groups as shown in the query in the fiddle using linq2sql.

However, EntityFramework obfuscates the join table, `TblUserGroup` and instead just gives me the navigation properties: `TblGroups.Users` or `User.TblGroups`

This is what I have put together thus far but Linqpad tells me it cannot execute:

```
var maxGroup = from ua in ctx.TblGroups
               group ua by ua.TblUsers.Select(s=>s.UserId)
               into g
               select new
               {
                   UserId= g.Key,
                   MaxLevel = g.Max(s => s.GroupLevel)
               };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you can do it like this:

```
var result = users.Select(u => new 
                               {
                                   UserId = u.Id, 
                                   MaxLevel = u.Groups.Max(g => g.GroupLevel) 
                               });
```

Having:

```
class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get;set; }

    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public int GroupLevel { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because not all users are in a group, the `Max` function fails when it encounters a `NULL` value. I have updated my sql fiddle. **EDIT:** ah hah, it works if I cast the value into a nullable type!

Answer (score -1):

Does it work for you?

```
var maxGroup = ctx.TblUsers
    .Where(u => u.TblUserGroups != null)
    .Select(u => new 
            {
                UserId = u.UserId, 
                MaxGroupLevel = u.TblUserGroups.TblGroups.Max(g => g.GroupLevel) 
            }
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't work because Entity Framework does not generate a class for the join table, `TblUserGroups`

Comment: Ok I understand. I have just noticed this in your question